# Send post to URL using js/html

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to find if its possible to send POST to url using only html and javascript.
According to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) its not possible. Can anyone knowledgeable tell me is it possible ? and if it's how to do it? 
ad1
Without using jQuery

Comment: Take a look here it may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As per the article, if the URL is not in the same origin, it is not possible. This is for security reasons.

If it's within the same origin (domain) then it is possible.

Pure JS (no frameworks) examples here: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp

Comment: Hmm but its possible to send post to url from localhost using any known to me script language.

Comment: @whd — There is a big difference between making an HTTP request from your server and making an HTTP request from your visitor's browser. You are responsible for your server, you are not responsible for your visitor's browser (your visitor is).

Comment: But it isn't true that it isn't possible, there are a number of ways to circumvent the same origin policy. It is only impossible under default conditions when you are trying to make a straight request.

Comment: the given link broken

Answer (score 2):

If you consider jQuery to be JavaScript it sure is.

See here:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

If you're going to be doing a lot of this sort of thing in your development in the future, I'd highly recommend you get used to using jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to you can use [XMLHttpRequest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest). All major browsers support it.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm trying to find if its possible to send POST to url using only html and javascript.

Yes

> According to *this* its not possible.

No. The Same Origin Policy, in general, prevents you *reading* data from different origins. Pre-flight checks sometimes prevent you sending data, but there are [several ways to circumvent the policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy).

> and if it's how to do it? ad1 Without using jQuery

[XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest) and [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) are well documented.